# Examples of matrix items vs non matrix items in netsuite item csv upload

Tags: csv, netsuite

I'm trying to set up my items in NetSuite and I have matrix options as we are overlaying a website.

NetSuite has supplied me with examples of how to set up matrix options i.e. with Parent and child relationships. However when I upload simple items (that don't have matrix items) I am getting a lot of errors

How do I set up a non matrix item? Do I still need to state that there is a parent/child relationship?

Comment: Non-matrix items do not have parent-child relationships.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the same mapping for importing non-matrix items. You will need to create a different mapping for ordinary Inventory Items.